# Sticky Navigation - Using stickUp.js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
main {} .bckgrnd {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#break {
  clear: both;
}
div {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10%;
  max-width: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header {
  height: 60vh;
}
#header-slide .bckgrnd {
  background-image: url("../img/headerslide.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  /*restrains the image to the size of the viewport */
}
#navigation ul {
  padding: 5px 10%;
  opacity: 0.1;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 6vh;
  width: 100%;
  !important
}
#navigation li {
  float: left;
  background-color: none;
  list-style: none;
}
#intro-main {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #373B44;
}
#mse {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000000;
  background-image: url("../img/mse.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#isg {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  background-image: url("../img/isg.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#about {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: #A8A8A8;
}
#credits {
  height: 4vh;
  background-color: #101010;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<!--<![endif]-->

<html class="no-js">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Mse &amp; Isg</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Embroidery Ads Coveralls Signs Graphic Decals">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
</head>

<body>


  <main>

    <header id="header-slide" class "header">

      <div class="bckgrnd" data-center="background-position: 100% 0px;" data-top-bottom="background-position: 100% -250px;">

      </div>

      <!--navigation-->
      <nav id="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>About Us</li>
          <li>Mse</li>
          <li>Isg</li>
          <li>Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    </header>

    <div id="intro-main">
    </div>

    <div id="mse">
    </div>

    <div id="isg">
    </div>

    <div id="about">
    </div>

    <div id="credits">

    </div>


  </main>

  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/skrollr.js"></script>
  <script src="js/stickUp.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--skrollr initialize-->
    var s = skrollr.init({
      forceHeight: false
    });

     //initiating jQuery
    jQuery(function($) {
      $(document).ready(function()



        //enabling stickUp on the navbar
        $('#navigation').stickUp();
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm a bit new to coding, although I did take computer science in college, I have never been able to use it until now.

Here is the problem: I am making a website for a company and I pretty much have the layout done.

It's just the sticky navigation bar that is acting weird, it goes on the right side when scrolled down(i'ts supposed to stick after you scroll down and retain 100%width).

I am using a free jquery plugin that is called stickUp.js and I am not sure if it might be a compatibilty issue with skrollr.
This is the plugin that I am using and the way I want the navbar to act, except to retain the width 100% the whole page.  http://lirancohen.github.io/stickUp/

Here is the view of the problem:
http://adventcomp.com/beta/index.html

The image files are quite big, I have no plans in using them. They are just place holders for now,
as I will be using skrollr in this site so do not worry.

TIA

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the width of the navigation bar to 100% when it becomes sticky. That should fix the problem.

Comment: Well, that would take the semantic meaning of the code. Technically I shouldn't be touching the js script as it is already been predefined and only a plugin. 

I can use a <div>, it will be centered but the width won't go from side to side as i have a margin on both ends.

Comment: @kennikuyou -- the width of the navigation is set via css not js and learn about fixed, absolute, relative, and static positioning so you can understand that this is the correct answer. Alternatively you can also set the left and right to 0 via css.

Comment: @Christina - so how do I put it in code then; setting the width of the navbar to 100%? via css?

Kinda confusing if it's the sticky js plugin thats the one whos controlling it.

Comment: The script adds a class .isStuck (check the docs) you use that in combo with the navigation's id or class and set the css. See example of the Bryce Snyder answer.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you're making a sticky header you have to add a position: fixed to it.

I would use:

```
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here's an example in CodePen.

http://codepen.io/brycesnyder/pen/dPbxqE

Comment: Yes it is a sticky header, but I am planning to put it on half way on the page after it is loaded so it only sticks when u scroll down after you've reach the navbar.

Something like this:
http://lirancohen.github.io/stickUp/

Comment: Are you using JQuery? @kennikuyou

Comment: Yes, it is in the snippets I think.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to stick elements to the top and span the width of the viewport.

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using Following css it will solve your problem,

```
.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}
```

Also u can use bootstrap plugin for good layout for your site. here is the link of bootstrap,
[Bootstrap plugin with example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/)